# root automatically set as mounted directory owner

Tags: mount, fstab

I made an entry in fstab for my USB HDD

```
PARTUUID=xxxyyyzzz-01 /mnt/usbstorage vfat   defaults,nofail   0   0
```

I made the owner of the /mnt/usbstorage to be pi (so that when i run apps as pi, there are no issues loading data to it)

```
pi@raspberrypi:/mnt $ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Jul 15 15:37 usbstorage
```

however, as soon as i mount the USB, root becomes the owner. How do i avoid this?

```
pi@raspberrypi:/mnt $ sudo mount -a
pi@raspberrypi:/mnt $ ls -l
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 32768 Dec 31  1969 usbstorage
```

Cross posted [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=217648&p=1342038)

Comment: maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204641/automatically-mount-a-drive-using-etc-fstab-and-limiting-access-to-all-users-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mounting a *vfat* file system there are particular options. You can set `uid=<value>` (user id) and `gid=<value>` (group id) in *fstab* so it looks like for example:

```
PARTUUID=xxxyyyzzz-01 /mnt/usbstorage vfat   defaults,nofail,uid=1000,gid=1000   0   0
```

Of course you have to use the `uid` and `gid` from your user. 1000 is that one from user *pi*. You can get it with `id <username>`.